# print values that occur in one column but not another

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file with four columns of data that looks like this:

```
cluster-9  cluster-12   cluster-40  cluster-62
cluster-10 cluster-12   cluster-42  cluster-60
cluster-12 cluster-12   cluster-43  cluster-61
cluster-12 cluster-12   cluster-28  cluster-20
cluster-12 cluster-12   cluster-29  cluster-21
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-41  cluster-63
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-2   cluster-4
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-8   cluster-5
cluster-16 cluster-9    cluster-9   cluster-6
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-45  cluster-39
```

I would like to extract the unique values that are in column 1, but not in a specific other column (pairwise). So for example i'd like to be able to compare column 1 and 2 and output that only the following are in column 1 but not column 2:

```
cluster-10
cluster-16
```

Because cluster-12 and cluster-9 are found in column 2 they are not printed.

Comment: I've managed to extract the columns of interest, and find the unique values in each column, but i'm a bit lost from there:

awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ; { print $1, $2 }' FILENAME | uniq

Comment: Separate the columns and sort-unique them. Then see the [`comm`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucomm.htm) command, which is specifically designed for this.

Comment: ...and maybe a little sed to clean the results.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{a[$1];b[$2]} END{for(i in a){if(i in b){continue};print i}}' Input_file
cluster-10
cluster-16
```

Let's say we want to send values of columns which we want to compare in variables(`awk` variables) then try following.

```
awk -v col1="1" -v col2="2" '{a[$col1];b[$col2]} END{for(i in a){if(i in b){continue};print i}}'  Input_file
cluster-10
cluster-16
```

Change values of variables `-v col1` and `-v col2` as per new column values which you want to compare and it will compare their values then(check to get one columns unique values seeing other column).

Comment: Yah, I've been beaten.

Comment: @tshiono, only this time buddy :)

Comment: `'{a[$1]; b[$2]} END{for (i in a) if (!(i in b)) print i}'`

Answer (score 0):

There are of course multiple ways to accomplish this, but here's one using `sed`, `sort`, and `uniq`. The key here is to find the unique set of each of the two columns you care about and then use the `-u` option to `uniq` to print only the items in the first set. The code below looks at columns 1 and 2, but you could easily adjust to look at any other pair of columns.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#define a separator character and a column format, adjust to fit your data
sep=" "
col="\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\)$sep"

#get all values in column 1 and reduce to a unique set
col1=`sed "s/^$col.*/\\1/" file | sort | uniq`
#get all values in column2 and reduce to a unique set. Adjust for a different 
#column as necessary
col2=`sed "s/^$col$col.*/\\2/" file | sort | uniq`
#concatenate our results and spit out only unique items.
#Include column 2 twice so that we don't get any items only in column2
echo "$col1$col2$col2" | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: Thanks! This mostly works, but it seems that the last echo command is such that it takes the last value of col1 and puts it on the same line as the first item of col2 which means that the last and first items are viewed as unique. is there anyway to add a line break after echoing col1?

Comment: Interesting, I'm not seeing the same behavior. With the `-e` option to echo, it will accept backslash escape sequences (such as for an extra newline). I'll try to take a more detailed look later. Ravinder Singh's answer below is much more succinct though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$ perl -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}++; $kv2{$F[1]}++; END { for(keys %kv) { unless ($kv2{$_}) { print "$_" } }}' greg.txt
cluster-10
cluster-16
$ cat greg.txt
cluster-9  cluster-12   cluster-40  cluster-62
cluster-10 cluster-12   cluster-42  cluster-60
cluster-12 cluster-12   cluster-43  cluster-61
cluster-12 cluster-12   cluster-28  cluster-20
cluster-12 cluster-12   cluster-29  cluster-21
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-41  cluster-63
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-2   cluster-4
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-8   cluster-5
cluster-16 cluster-9    cluster-9   cluster-6
cluster-16 cluster-12   cluster-45  cluster-39
$
```

or

```
$ perl -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}++; $kv2{$F[1]}++; END { for(keys %kv) { print unless $kv2{$_} }} ' greg.txt
cluster-10
cluster-16
$
```